# How to use abs and div with fixed-size integers

Tags: c, c99, stdint

In C99 we have fixed-size integer types, defined in *stdint.h*.
In *stdlib.h* we have the *abs* and *div* functions which operate on *int*s, as well as their *long int/long long int* counterparts *labs*, *llabs*, *ldiv*, *lldiv*.

Since the size of int/long/long long varies based on platform and used compiler I wonder how to chose the right variant of *abs/div* when using fixed-size integers like int16_t, int32_t or int64_t?

Comment: Enable more warnings, and the compiler will tell you. And if you're worried, err on the safe side and always use the `long long` versions.

Comment: There are also the `intmax_t` variants. And you could define your own set of functions if you want to use a function instead of directly writing the equivalent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, that you are able to use a C11 compiler, you could use *Generic macros* feature and define wrapper, that covers fixed-size integers. An example might look like:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define safe_abs(n) _Generic((n), \
    signed char: abs(n), short: abs(n), int: abs(n), long: labs(n), long long: llabs(n))

int main(void)
{
    int8_t n1 = -123;
    printf("n1 = %" PRId8 "\n", safe_abs(n1));

    int16_t n2 = -1234;
    printf("n2 = %" PRId16 "\n", safe_abs(n2));

    int32_t n3 = -123456;
    printf("n3 = %" PRId32 "\n", safe_abs(n3));

    int64_t n4 = -12345678910;
    printf("n4 = %" PRId64 "\n", safe_abs(n4));

    return 0;
}
```

The trick is that these fixed-size integers are just type definitions for *standard integer types*.